# Young boy with talking computer that turns evil, estranged father saves him in the end

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror

This is a horror novel I read about 15 years ago. I’d say it probably was published in the 80’s or 90’s.

The plot was about a bright boy who had a talking computer friend (had some sort of clever acronym for a name I’m sure, maybe CAL? CHIPS?) that he spent a lot of time with. I think his parents were separated which is why he spent time with the computer.

The computer turns evil somehow and plots to kill the boy. Eventually his estranged father helps save them and I think everyone gets back together.

I’m pretty sure it was a small paperback all in black and I think the boy was screaming on the front cover. I desperately need to know this book!

Comment: Also posted to https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/q2n2nt/boy_gets_closer_to_talking_computer_pal_who_turns/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been solved! It's ***[The Shadow Man](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2662849-the-shadow-man)*** (1986) by Stephen Gresham.

From Goodreads:

> Joey felt a chill as he stared at the luminous green dots on the screen of his *Computer*Assisted*Playmate. What did CAP know about The Shadow Man? Joey's dad said there was nothing to be scared of because The Shadow Man wasn't real. But CAP, Joey's best friend in the world, would never lie to him. Or let anything bad happen to him.
>
> But even CAP can't help Joey when The Shadow Man comes to visit him. The Shadow Man can hide anywhere. Under the bed. In the closet. Behind the mirror. The Shadow Man can even make Joey do things a little boy should never do. Especially when it hides in the sophisticated circuitry of the one thing Joey trusts most...

[image]